# Mac users create text with non standard accents

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

When a Mac OSX 10.3 user inputs text in Wordpress, his accented characters such as é or è are not rendered correctly on Firefox and Safari. The accent is shown too high in relation to the letter.

When I edit the text using a Windows computer, I need to press backspace twice to erase the letter. The first time it transforms the é to e and it requires a second time to erase the e.

How can I make the Mac format the accents correctly?

Edit :
Trying to paste the char here

Faulty : è

Not faulty : è

EDIT2 : I managed to get the unicode code(?) :

Combined : e0x300

One char : 0xE8

Comment: OS X 10.3 ? really? That's a 10-year-old OS, I doubt anyone would remember why it did or didn't do something specific.

Comment: How does the middle paragraph about Windows relate to the question?

Comment: The middle paragraph indicates that the Mac user has inserted not a single accented character, but two overlapping characters. Seems relevant to me.

Comment: fixer1234 > usually, you press backspace once to erase a char. I only have access to Linux and Windows computers.

Comment: Tetsujin> i'll ask users again, It should not be a 10 years old mac. I have no mac.

Comment: removing an accented char on Mac shouldn't take 2 attempts; the glyph should be a composite once generated, from either press & hold or opt/dead-key, key.  ü é å ç ñ just as examples

Comment: I take 2 attempt on windows/Linux, in wordpress admin as well as in Sublime text.

Comment: Perhaps it's OSX 10.10.3?

Comment: So the issue is how to input the correct (single), Unicode character in Wordpress?